# C++ Problem with accessing a specific record in a TXT file

Tags: c++

I am a beginner at programming.
I am having problems updating records in a Bank Management System project I am making using C++. So I made a test case on the side discovering something weird.
When I access a record and try to print only the first three entries. There are no problems.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   fstream file(“t.txt”);

   int a; string b; int c;
   int p = 1;
   while(file>>a>>b>>c){
       if(a == 1){
           cout <<a<<b<<" "<<c;
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

But when I try to print the fourth entry, it does not print anything at all.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   fstream file(“t.txt”);

   int a; string b; int c; int d;
   int p = 1;
   while(file>>a>>b>>c>>d){
       if(a == 1){
           cout <<a<<b<<" "<<c<<d;
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Here is the text file;

```
0 husnain 20
1 husnain 21 22222222
2 husnain 22
3 husnain 23
4 husnain 24
```

Also, is there a way to print the full name with a space between first and last name?

Comment: if thats the file contents then the first version should also fail to produce expected output at some point. edit: oh well, you just dont notice because `a==1` is before it fails

Comment: so in general strings are hard to deal with if they contain spaces (so if you know a name has first and last name you would read them as two strings instead of one).

Comment: Consider using other delimiter (like comma or tab) when data to deal with contains spaces.

Comment: Use a debugger to see what's up.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your answers. You all were a great help.